# How do I reset the Distortion World puzzle?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

I accidentally put the wrong boulder in the wrong hole and now I’m stuck in the Distortion World.

I tried saving and reloading my game and leaving the area and coming back but the boulder wont reload.

How can I reset the puzzle? Do I need to restart the whole game?

Comment: No because I have tried those things and it didn’t work. Like I stated on the question

Comment: Hi Tahlia, welcome to Arqade! Did you already try talking to "one of the lake trio", as suggested in the second answer? Since your question is essentially the same, it will probably be closed as a duplicate. However, if the answers there won't work for you, we can draw attention to that fact. The activity around your question will help, and I edited the duplicate, so that will also resurface on the main page.

Comment: Please do i have tried all the answers abd none have worked